# deleted sample package still getting compile error

Tags: java, javafx, compiler-errors, package

I'm creating a project in JavaFX and when I created a new project it gave me a package named sample. I decided not to use the packaging, cut and pasted all my classes into the src package, and made my fxml file. I am getting an error that looks like java is looking for a sample package but I deleted it. I can't find anything in my code that shows sample referenced anywhere. Any ideas?

```
 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\alloy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\annotations.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\asm-all.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\asm-commons.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\asm-tree-3.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\asm.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\asm4-all.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\automaton.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\batik.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\boot.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\cglib-2.2.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\cli-parser-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\commons-codec-1.8.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1-patched.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\commons-net-3.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\ecj-4.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\extensions.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\fluent-hc-4.3.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\forms_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\freemarker.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\fxHelpBrowser.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\groovy-all-2.3.9.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\gson-2.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\guava-17.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\httpclient-4.3.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\httpcore-4.3.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\httpmime-4.3.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\icons.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\idea-jsp-openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\idea.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\ideax.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\isorelax.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jasper21_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jasper2_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\javac2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jaxen-1.1.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jayatana-1.2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jcip-annotations.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jdkAnnotations.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jdom.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jettison-1.3.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jgoodies-common-1.2.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jgoodies-forms.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jgoodies-looks-2.4.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jh.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jing.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jna-utils.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jna.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jps-launcher.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jps-model.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jps-server.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch-0.1.51.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.connector-factory.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.core.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.pageant.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.sshagent.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsr166e.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsr173_1.0_api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jzlib-1.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\log4j.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\markdown4j-2.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\markdownj-core-0.4.2-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\microba.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\miglayout-swing.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\nekohtml-1.9.14.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\netty-all-4.1.0.Beta4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\optimizedFileManager.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\oromatcher.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\picocontainer.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\protobuf-2.5.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\proxy-vole_20131209.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\pty4j-0.4.15.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\purejavacomm.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\resolver.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\rhino-js-1_7R4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\rngom-20051226-patched.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\sanselan-0.98-snapshot.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\serviceMessages.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\snappy-in-java-0.3.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\swingx-core-1.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\trang-core.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\trove4j.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\trove4j_src.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\velocity.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\winp-1.21-patched.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xbean.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xerces.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xml-apis.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xmlrpc-2.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xpp3-1.1.4-min.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xstream-1.4.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\yjp-controller-api-redist.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\JavaEE\lib\gradle-javaee.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\JavaEE\lib\IntelliLang-javaee.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\JavaEE\lib\javaee-openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\JavaEE\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\PersistenceSupport\lib\persistence-openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\PersistenceSupport\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\DatabaseTools\lib\database-openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\DatabaseTools\lib\jdba.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\DatabaseTools\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\CSS\lib\css-openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\CSS\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\uml\lib\diagram-api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\Spring\lib\spring-aop.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\Spring\lib\spring-api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\Spring\lib\spring-eclipse.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\Spring\lib\spring-web.jar;C:\Users\Ethan\workspace\CSC 275 Final\out\production\CSC 275 Final" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain sample.Main
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: mhm did you have close your terminal/console ? it seems like the terminal had still load the old project

Comment: I didn't try that. I'll try that next

Comment: Just an editing note: that's a runtime error, not a compile error. You might want to edit the title of your question and the tags accordingly. And it seems specific to your IDE (IntelliJ) as (if you scroll far enough to the right) you can see it's still trying to execute `sample.Main`: so it's a configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have some problems with project configuration. So, in IDEA try to: "Run" -> "EditConfiguration" and check your settings.
[image]

If you haven't any class names on the left section (like my MainSTE, MainSCI) - just add it: "+" -> "Application", and specify the class name (underlined button on my screenshot)